# Recursive Group member function returns 'Object is disposed' error

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, active-directory

I'm trying to write a simple function i can call to recursively obtain the group members of a group in Active Directory but i'm getting the 'Object is disposed' error on an object i don't think i'm disposing of (But could be wrong):

```
namespace ADPlayArround
{
    using System;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var groupMembers = GetGroupMembership("SL-FILE-DAF-Agriculture-RID-PIFT", true);

            // I get the error here saying 'Cannot access a disposed object'
            foreach (var member in groupMembers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(member.SamAccountName);
            }
        }

        private static PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> GetGroupMembership (string groupName, bool recurse = false)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> members;

            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

                members = @group?.GetMembers(recurse);

                return members;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before posting this question i looked up on the using statement and correct ways to dispose an object, from what i can understand i am disposing the PrincipalContext called context (because i don't need it after the method call) but i am not disposing of the PrincipalSearchResult called members (because i want to return this list of Principals) but i'm receiving an error indicating that it's still being disposed of?

My theories are:

- **members is being disposed somehow** (I just can't find out how)
- *Disposing of the PrincipalContext is somehow causing a chain-dispose call* (Unlikely but i don't know enough C# to rule it out)

So i guess my question is:

**Is the members variable being disposed somehow or is there a flaw in my code that i am not picking up on?**

As a bonus, is there an easy way to list the parent group of the Principal to see a path of groups like

Group1\Group2\User1

Comment: note: you are not executing recursively, you just call a function in a loop.
recursion is when a function call itself ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion )

Comment: You are correct, my function is not doing any recursion but from what i have read it calls the GetMembers function on the GroupPrincipal object which does the recursion for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ILSpy I could see the code for getting SamAccountName:

```
public string SamAccountName
{
    [SecurityCritical]
    get
    {
        return this.HandleGet<string>(ref this.samName, "Principal.SamAccountName", ref this.samNameChanged);
    }
    [SecurityCritical]
    set
    {
        if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, StringResources.InvalidNullArgument, new object[]
            {
                "Principal.SamAccountName"
            }));
        }
        if (!this.GetStoreCtxToUse().IsValidProperty(this, "Principal.SamAccountName"))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(StringResources.InvalidPropertyForStore);
        }
        this.HandleSet<string>(ref this.samName, value, ref this.samNameChanged, "Principal.SamAccountName");
    }
}
```

Now let see what inside HandleGet<> function:

```
[SecurityCritical]
internal T HandleGet<T>(ref T currentValue, string name, ref LoadState state)
{
    this.CheckDisposedOrDeleted();
    if (state == LoadState.NotSet)
    {
        this.LoadIfNeeded(name);
        state = LoadState.Loaded;
    }
    return currentValue;
}
```

Another step, take a look into LoadIfNeeded:

```
[SecurityCritical]
internal void LoadIfNeeded(string principalPropertyName)
{
    if (!this.fakePrincipal && !this.unpersisted)
    {
        this.ctx.QueryCtx.Load(this, principalPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Viola! It tries to access PrincipalContext (ctx) which was disposed earlier.

Comment: It's interesting that it holds the context like that, thanks for taking the time to help me out. +1